# How to merge features contained in a shapefile based on a condition in R

Tags: r, merge, shapefile

I have attached a shapefile (`sample`) with 4 features and each of them have `gap`,`out`,`in` in the field `type` (Refer to the attribute table). I would like to merge feature `gap` feature with the adjacent polygon which has the maximum area (In this case the `gap` would be merged with `in`).
My final shapefile would have 3 features (without `gap`). How do I do this in R?

In ArcGIS, there is a direct tool to merge feature. I wanted to know how we do this in R.

[Here is the link to the shapefile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19lHsyAdBVHFxmZwRdaWiM7fBWHn9-PdU) 
[image: This is a sample shapefile in which there are 4 features]

[image: This is the legend to the respective shapefile]

[image: This is the attribute table for the shapefile]

I have used `rgeos` library to figure out the adjacent polygon with the maximum area. This is my code. I can't figure out how to merge this feature with the `gap` feature.

```
library(rgeos)
adj_mat <- gTouches(shp, byid=TRUE)
a <- adj_mat[which(shp@data$type=="gap"),]
area <- shp@data$SHAPE_Area[which(a=="TRUE")]
final_matching_id <- which(area==max(area))
f_gap <- shp@data[final_matching_id+1,]
f_gap

  OBJECTID SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area type
3       13   1.527046 0.09469124   in
```

Comment: Please indicate what you've done to try and solve this problem yourself. And also, please share sample data if you expect people to attempt something on your behalf. Edit: also, you're going to have to indicate what the merger should look like for the data. E.g., is `SHAPE_Leng` additive, and so forth.

Comment: @Dunois I have shared the shapefile and code which I have used for identifying the adjacent polygon.

Comment: @Dunois In my final shapefile, the `gap` feature should be completely merged with the `in` feature. A simple merge of polygons would be sufficient I feel. I am not sure about that.

Comment: Erm, you still need to share some sample data. What is `shp`? Edit: how is adjacency determined? Is there a column which indicates which `OBJECTID` is adjacent to which other `OBJECTID`s?

Comment: @Dunois `shp` is the shapefile read using `readOGR` from `rgdal`. `SHAPE_Leng` is the perimeter. While merging as I said, the properties of `gap` should merge with the `in` (here the `object ID`=13). So the final `object ID` would be 13.

Comment: @Dunois Adjacency is determined using the function `gTouches` from `rgeos` it provides us with the (spatial) adjacency matrix of all features.

Answer (score 1):

`gUnion` and `spRbind` maybe solve your problem.

```
merged_d <- gUnion(shp[which(shp@data$type=="gap"),], shp[final_matching_id+1,])
not_related_d <- shp[c(1:4)[-c(which(shp@data$type=="gap"), final_matching_id+1)],]

shp2 <- spRbind(merged_d, not_related_d)

plot(shp2, col = 2:4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I can't view the attribute table of `shp2`. It is SpatialPolygons right?